# How to use decorators on methods?

Tags: python, methods, decorator

How do I use decorators on methods, putting it outside the class just returns a memory address: `<function decor at 0x104e167b8>`, and putting it inside raises a

`TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callabl`

I have also tried adding `*args` since there is a `self` in the method's parameter.

Comment: Can you post your code so we can understand your question better?

Comment: Can you provide some code examples for these errors?

Comment: Maybe a look in the [Documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/229/decorators#t=201708121148482706389) might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A sample implementation of a decorator within a class goes like this:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def decor(function):
        def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
            # Whatever your decorator does here
            return function(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrap

    @decor
    @staticmethod
    def bar():
        pass
```

Or calling this on an instance of `Foo`:

```
foo = Foo()
foo.bar()
```

If your decorator needs access to `self`:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, spam):
        if spam is not None:
            self.spam = spam

    def require_spam(function):
        def wrap(self, *args, **kwargs):
            try:
                self.spam
            except AttributeError:
                return
            return function(self, *args, **kwargs)
        return wrap

    @require_spam
    def bar(self):
        pass
```